# Strange behaviour of custom schema for Sygic on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, custom-url, sygic

In phonegap application for iOS I'm trying to open **Sygic** navigation app in javascript by it's custom schema URL. **Everything works** for native iOS navigation, Google Maps, Waze.... but not for Sygic! It's very strange because direct link tapped by user works:

```
<a href="com.sygic.aura://coordinate|16.6784149|48.8759607|drive">
```

In Javascript all these doesn't works:

```
window.location = 'com.sygic.aura://coordinate|16.6784149|48.8759607|drive';

window.open('com.sygic.aura://coordinate|16.6784149|48.8759607|drive', '_system');

window.open('com.sygic.aura://coordinate|16.6784149|48.8759607|drive', '_blank', 'location=yes');

var t = escape('com.sygic.aura://coordinate|16.6784149|48.8759607|drive');
window.location.href = t;
```

One of suspect was pipe "|" in url. After escaping url still not working... WHY IT WORKS FOR FOR EVERYTHING ELSE BUT NOT FOR "**com.sygic.aura**" ?

Comment: hey i was wondering if you managed to open it via Phonegap, I am struggeling both on android / ios in my phonegap app

Comment: Hi I'm getting the same issue now, on iOS 8.3 and Cordova.

Comment: A recent Sygic update caused my deep links to stop working; I figured out that the pipe now needs to be escaped, e.g. `com.sygic.aura://coordinate%7C16.6784149%7C48.8759607%7Cdrive`

Comment: so is it working? escaping the pipe doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is official answer from Sygic:

Thank you for your feedback, we already know about this issue and are working on the fix. However, this can be only fixed in one of the future updates of the application. I would like to ask for your patience, as it will be solved as fast as possible. Make sure you have automatic updates enabled for our application to receive the update instantly when it is released.

Feel free to contact me back in case of any questions or issues, I will be glad to help.

Thank you for your patience and understanding.